# Windows Perf Counters on Docker containers : System.InvalidOperationException: Category does not exist

Tags: performancecounter, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, docker

I am running a .net application in a windows docker container with **Docker Desktop for Windows**. When my app tries to create perf counters using this code:

```
_counter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, InstanceName, true);
//My categoryname  is Processor , CounterName is % Processor Time & instancename is _Total.
```

I am getting this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Category does
>   not exist.    at
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine,
>   String category, String counter)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()    at
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName,
>   String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)

This is the base image of my container: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/

It has Windows Server core as part of it.

Appreciate any help in fixing this. I am not sure if this is just some windows setting I need to change here or is it because of the docker & windows or my code not able to access the categories of the perf counters.

It is working perfectly fine, when I run it in my local machine instead of a container.

Comment: I figured out few things : 
1. It actually means that the category Processor is not present in my OS for some reason. When I tried to list all the performance categories by this code : 
PerformanceCounterCategory[] categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory category in categories)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Category name: {0}", category.CategoryName);

}

There was not a category called Processor. Why is it missing in Windows Server 2016?

Comment: I have the same issue but with a Windows 2022 image. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know these should be working.

Can you try using TypePerf to query those counters? I see them on my system when I query them on the Windows Server core base image. Do they break in the container you built?

`docker run microsoft/windowsservercore TypePerf "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"`

Does show CPU usage:

`"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\DF4E02B31BBD\Processor(0)\% Processor Time","\\DF4E02B31BBD\Processor(1)\% Processor Time","\\DF4E02B31BB
D\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
"04/25/2017 09:52:34.412","50.536535","38.170669","44.353602"
"04/25/2017 09:52:35.423","19.583557","2.572386","11.077971"
"04/25/2017 09:52:36.425","39.207660","50.119106","44.663383"
"04/25/2017 09:52:37.453","31.606146","43.765053","37.685600"`